# Prove for Groups $A,B$ that $A\times B\cong B\times A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

So I need to show that for groups $A,B$ that
$$A\times B\cong B\times A$$
So i gather that I have to show that there exists a bijective homomorphsim between the two groups, and so the natural morphism I thought was 
$$\phi((a,b))=(b,a)$$

But I have to show first that this IS a homomorphism.  So I consider two elements of $A\times B$.  So let $(a,b), (c,d)\in A\times B$ where $a,c\in A, b,d\in B$.  Then
$$\phi((a,b)*(c,d))=\phi(a\square c,b\circ d)=(b\circ d,a\square c)=\phi((b,a)*(d,c))$$

I feel this is getting me nowhere.

Comment: Right idea. Wrong execution. Show that it splits nicely in the second step.

Comment: You almost have it, but your last equality is incorrect. Do you see why?

Comment: so then $(b\circ d, a\square c)=(b,a)*(d,c)$?

Comment: Exactly, now express $(b, a)$ and $(d, c)$ using $\phi$ and you should have it

Comment: and the $(b,a)*(d,c)=\phi((a,b))@\phi((c,d))$?

Comment: @manthanomen, Okay.  Then injectivity seems straight forward.  But the surjectivity... if $(x,y)\in B\times A$, such that $(x,y)=\phi(a,b)=(b,a)$ and thus $x=b, y=a$ and surjective?

Comment: @Lalaloopsy All you have to do is show that $(x, y) \in B \times A$ equals $\phi$ of something in $A \times B$. So I would just say $(x, y) = \phi(y, x)$ and $(y, x) \in A \times B$.